# get parent values inside a set

Tags: salesforce, apex

Account has a field `Source_System__c` as its parent.

I wanna query Name, Id from Source_System

This query is workable. 
[SELECT Source_System__r.Name, Source_System__r.Id from Account]

However, I wanna have the value from Source_System can be nested in an object.
Like the sub-query's result. But it didn't work.

```
SELECT (SELECT Name, Id from Source_System) FROM Account
                         ^
```

ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
Didn't understand relationship 'Source_System' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

```
SELECT (SELECT Name, Id from Source_System__r) FROM Account
                         ^
```

ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
Didn't understand relationship 'Source_System__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question `Account` is child here and `Source_System__c` is parent.

```
SELECT Source_System__r.Name, Source_System__r.Id FROM Account
```

This query will work because your are using child-to-parent relationship. But you can't query like `SELECT (SELECT Name, Id from Source_System) FROM Account`.

Because the inner query object should be child of account. Here you can use parent-to-child relationship in aggregate query like this:

```
SELECT Id,Name,
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM Accounts__r
  )
FROM Source_System__c
```

Please refer [Using Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm)